# Casting generic class to dynamic type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, casting

I have a generic class that I want to cast to a dynamic generic, but I get a `Cannot convert type MyGeneric1<MyTypedClass1> to MyGeneric1<dynamic>` error message. Is this kind of cast to `dynamic` possible, and if so then please explain.

Here is where I try to cast a typed `MyGeneric1` generic class into a `dynamic` `MyGeneric1`.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static MyGeneric1<dynamic> ToDynamic(this MyGeneric1<MyTypedClass1> myObj1)
    {
        return (MyGeneric1<dynamic>)myObj1;
    }
}
```

The `MyGeneric1` class is defined like so:

```
public class MyGeneric1<T> : DynamicObject { // Code here ... }
```

The `MyTypedClass1` class is defined like so:

```
public class MyTypedClass1: DynamicObject { // Code here ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyTypedClass1 is assignable to dynamic, as it inherits from it. But you cannot simply cast generic classes, when they have different generic arguments, even when arguments themselves are valid for assigning (as MyTypedClass1 and dynamic ).

But, you can create new instance with proper generic type and assign value for it:

```
   public class MyTypedClass1 : DynamicObject
   {
       public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
   }


   public class MyGeneric<T> : DynamicObject
   {
       // just some property to get the idea
       public T Value { get; set; }
   } 

   public static class MyGenericExtensions
   {
       public static MyGeneric<dynamic> ConveretGeneric(this MyGeneric<MyTypedClass1> argument)
       {
           return new MyGeneric<dynamic>()
           {
               // here you need to assign all needed properties
               Value = argument.Value
           };
       }
   }
```